# Error when importing sbt project due to powershell.exe missing

Tags: scala, powershell, sbt

I'm working on Windows 10 and tried to fix it by adding `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` as a PATH environment variable. But still getting the error:

```
List([error] java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.)
```

What could be another way to fix the failing sbt build?

Comment: Your PATH variable should already contain `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` (note: just the path, not `\powershell.exe` attached). If that is not the case, make sure you add it to the `System variables`, not the `User variables`. See [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/)

Comment: As mentioned - items in the `Path` environment variable should be directory names, not file names.

Comment: @Theo thank you! The problem was indeed due to the PATH variable was defined for both `System variables` and `User variables` AND had `\powershell.exe attached`. After removing it from User variables and deleting the file name the issue was fixed

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are already containing the path in PATH in path environment variable. Check it. If it still does not exist do one of the following from powershell:

```
# To change for current session
$env:path += ";$($PSHOME)"
```

```
# To change permanently 
cmd /c "Setx.exe %path% '%path%;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\"
```